# How to display java classes in eclipse calling a method from other class

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there is a quick way of identifying or displaying which classes are trying to call a method.

Its easy to do this if there are only few classes present. But what if there are hundreds of classes trying to call a method in other classes. It would be extremly tedious if I do this manually. Is there a plugin or some built-in functions that would do this in eclipse?

The reason am asking is I wanted to map out different classes that are calling methods from other classes for easy debugging.

Comment: This is one reason why you should strive for loose coupling and tight cohesion, to minimize the number of possible interactions to a manageable few. That being said, I don't know of a plug in for this.

Comment: Unfortunately am trying to maintain a code that was created by someone else. Its using loose coupling but I just find it really hard to trace or debug this style of programming especially if there are almost a thousand classes. But thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click your function, select references, and then choose what you want (generally project). That will show all the references to this function in the project. This also works for classes, variables, and probably other stuff too.

Comment: but not methods, I don't think.

Comment: It does, I just tested it. Moreover, it will differentiated between overloaded functions.

Comment: Dgrin91 is right, Ensure you select references being **in** the class that holds the method in question. For example, if you want to gather all references to `MyClass.myMethod()` you must open `MyClass` java source file, and select all references of `myMethod()` as dgrin91 said.

Comment: If you are using Juno R2, you would prefer clicking `Search` menu option from the menu bar and choose `Java Search` tab. You can search for a lot of stuff there

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Also make sure that you actually have the method selected with the blinking cursor on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try an eclipse's Call Hierarchy feature. It shows you all the methods which directly call the method you are interested in. You can expand each caller and see what methods call it and so on.

You can do it buy right clicking on the method and selecting an "Open Call Hierarchy" menu item or pressing `Ctrl+Alt+H` Hotkey.